# How to finish the proof of this corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hahn-banach-theorem

I'm reading **Corollary 0.1.3** of Hahn-Banach theorem:

> [image]

Because $f \restriction G = g$, $\|g\| \le \|f\|$. I'm unable to deduce $\|f\| \le \|g\|$ from the fact that $f(x) \le p(x) = \|g\| \|x\|$ for all $x \in E$. All I can do is $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} \le \|g\|$ for all $x \in E \setminus \{0\}$.

Could you please shed me some light?

Comment: Yes. The supremum is over $\|x\|=1$. (Also in the definition of $\|f\|_*$.)

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} = f\left(\frac x{\|x\|}\right)$. BTW, the theorem is really badly written because it is not said what $p$ is.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it ^o^ I misunderstand that $g$ is sublinear. It's indeed linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions are $\lVert f \rVert_* = \sup \{ \lvert f(x) \rvert \mid x \in E, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$ for $f \in E^*$, $\lVert g \rVert_{G^*} = \sup \{ \lvert g(x) \rvert \mid x \in G, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$ for $g \in G^*$.

Given $g  \in G^*$, the Hahn-Banach theorem provides a linear extension $f : E \to \mathbb R$ of $f$ such that $f(x) \le p(x) = \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} \lVert x \rVert$ for all $x \in E$. We deduce $-f(x) = f(-x) \le \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} \lVert -x \rVert = \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} \lVert x \rVert$. Therefore $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} \lVert x \rVert$ for all $x \in E$ which shows that $f$ is continuous, i.e. $f \in E^*$. We conclude
$$\lVert f \rVert_* = \sup \{ \lvert f(x) \rvert \mid x \in E, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \} \le \sup \{ \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} \lVert x \rVert \mid x \in E, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \} = \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} .$$
On the other hand
$$\lVert f \rVert_* = \sup \{ \lvert f(x) \rvert \mid x \in E, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \} \ge \sup \{ \lvert f(x) \rvert \mid x \in G, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}  = \sup \{ \lvert g(x) \rvert \mid x \in G, \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}  = \lVert g \rVert_{G^*} .$$